# MOSFET transistor with coupled drain and gate

Tags: mosfet

The below circuit is part of a КР580ВM80A, a clone of an Intel 8080 by [Vslav](https://github.com/1801BM1).

I'm trying to understand the purpose of coupled transistors T1 and T2. Vc is 12 V.

[image: Vc = 12V]

What will be "state" or voltage of point X for HI/LOW inputs at A and B. My guess is that for A = "HI" or B = "HI", output will be "LOW" and T1 and T2 will be "OFF".

For both A="LOW" and B="LOW", T3 and T4 are off and likely output will have high impedance.

Sorry if I my assumptions are wrong. I was learning digital electronic almost 20 years ago. Since then, I've been involved in software development. Thank you for any support.

Update:

Emulated the circuit (basically, this is a 3-state pin of the address bar controlled by internal state of the bit of address and inverted address bus enable signal). The simulation showed that voltage Vds = 0 of the FET with coupled drain and source.

Still, don't understand what is the actual purpose of it - what will happen if the gate of the next FET is directly connected to Vc (can't check it in simulator as had to tweak Vt to really high value +3.5V in order to make the circuit work as expected).

[image: simulation]

The free online app used to for simulation can be found [here](https://www.falstad.com/circuit/)

```
$ 1 0.000005 10.20027730826997 50 5 50 5e-11
f 160 96 224 96 32 3.7 0.02
f 240 176 304 176 32 3.7 0.02
w 224 112 224 176 0
w 224 176 240 176 0
w 224 80 224 48 0
w 160 96 160 48 0
w 304 160 304 48 0
f 256 304 304 304 32 3.7 0.02
f 144 304 192 304 32 3.7 0.02
w 192 288 192 256 0
w 192 256 304 256 0
w 256 304 256 368 0
w 256 368 80 368 0
w 144 304 112 304 0
w 96 96 96 304 0
w 96 304 112 304 0
f 336 208 384 208 32 3.7 0.02
w 304 208 336 208 0
w 384 192 384 48 0
w 256 368 336 368 0
f 336 368 384 368 32 3.7 0.02
w 96 96 96 16 0
w 64 16 96 16 0
w 96 16 448 16 0
g 192 320 192 336 0 0
g 304 320 304 336 0 0
f 448 144 512 144 32 3.7 0.02
g 512 128 512 80 0 0
w 512 160 512 192 0
f 560 112 624 112 32 3.7 0.02
w 560 112 560 48 0
w 624 96 624 48 0
w 624 128 624 272 0
f 448 320 512 320 32 3.7 0.02
w 512 304 512 272 0
g 512 336 512 432 0 0
f 672 112 720 112 32 3.7 0.02
w 672 112 672 48 0
w 720 96 720 48 0
w 512 192 656 192 0
f 672 272 720 272 32 3.7 0.02
w 624 272 672 272 0
w 656 192 720 192 0
g 720 288 720 320 0 0
f 768 192 816 192 32 3.7 0.02
f 784 368 816 368 32 3.7 0.02
g 816 384 816 432 0 0
w 624 272 624 368 0
w 624 368 784 368 0
w 816 176 816 96 0
g 384 384 384 432 0 0
w 816 272 864 272 0
v 784 112 784 48 0 0 40 10 0 0 0.5
g 784 112 784 128 0 0
w 816 96 896 96 0
v 896 160 896 96 0 0 40 5 0 0 0.5
g 896 160 896 192 0 0
v 64 112 64 16 0 2 80 2.5 2.5 0 0.5
v 80 432 80 368 0 2 40 2.5 2.5 0 0.5
g 64 112 64 144 0 0
g 80 432 80 464 0 0
w 784 48 720 48 0
w 720 48 672 48 0
w 672 48 624 48 0
w 624 48 560 48 0
w 560 48 384 48 0
w 384 48 304 48 0
w 304 48 224 48 0
w 224 48 160 48 0
w 304 192 304 208 0
w 304 208 304 256 0
w 304 256 304 288 0
w 384 224 384 272 0
w 448 16 448 144 0
w 448 144 448 320 0
w 384 272 512 272 0
w 512 272 624 272 0
w 816 208 816 272 0
w 816 352 816 272 0
w 384 272 384 352 0
w 720 128 720 192 0
w 720 192 720 256 0
w 720 192 768 192 0
o 47 64 0 4099 20 0.00009765625 0 6 47 3 57 0 57 3 58 0 58 3
```

Comment: A very warm welcome to the site. Please can you edit your question and (a) specify which 8-bit CPU and (b) split up the block of text with some blank lines for ease of reading. Thanks and, again, welcome.

Comment: What are the relative sizes of the four transistors? What is the approximate ratio of the supply voltage to the transistor threshold voltage?

Comment: Updated the question. Don't know anything about U-I characteristics of the transistors. Let's assume Vt = 0.7V

Comment: This is not my area of expertise, but it sure does look like a NOR gate (as you described).  Are T1 and T2 a depletion-mode load?  (I understand the concept, but don't know how it really looked in fabrication.)

Comment: I'm interested in this question, so +1. It brings to mind something I'd read some time back, but didn't fully apprehend at the time, about the "weak inversion" plateau (just before the threshold voltage itself.) Memory serving, this is an area that occurs just short of the point where the band-bending reaches about twice the difference between the intrinsic and actual Fermi levels of the semiconductor. But that's just a wag from memory and the only reason I'm mentioning it is to point out that monolithic mosfets aren't nearly as simple as often presented. I may learn something from an answer!

Comment: As @Theodore pointed out this is NOR gate. Have found that this configuration is called "the bootstrapped NMOS inverter". It's used when the output voltage must swing up to Vd. Also, it helps to handle the parasite capacitance Cp between point X and output, as during transition of output from low -> hi, T1 will be on and help to discharge the Cp.

Comment: https://patentimages.storage.googleapis.com/pdfs/04bed7f750956caf4291/US3506851.pdf
http://insanity4004.blogspot.com/2015/10/puzzling-out-bootstrap-load_13.html

Comment: @DraganS In the simulation, the issue may be that Falstad connects all the MOSFET body terminals to source, which is not how it's shown in the original schematic.